# Do you need to countersink self-countsink screws

Tags: tool-selection, screws

New to the forum and a bit clueless when it comes to DIY.  I'll be putting down some new floor boards and then laying subfloor sheet to give a nice even surface.

I'm using 18mm floorboards and 3mm hardboard sheets.  For the floorboards I was going to use [5 x 50mm Goldscrew Woodscrews Double Self-Countersunk screws](http://www.screwfix.com/p/goldscrew-woodscrews-double-self-countersunk-5-x-50mm-200-pack/16497) (image below).  Not sure what screws I'll be using for the hardboard yet.

[image: screw]

So my question is, do I need to countersink these screws?  And if I do what size of countersink tool should I use?  Any advice on the type / size of screws to use for the hardboard would be great as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So my question is, do I need to countersink these screws?

Since these are going to be used on the floorboards and overlaid with another layer of subfloor sheet, so long as you screw these in enough that they don't stick proud of the floorboard surface, I see no need to countersink.

> And if I do what size of countersink tool should I use?

It's hard to answer that question.  Countersink bits are all kinds of different sizes and slopes, so you'd be better off going to the store with a screw and seeing what will work.

[Rockler](http://www.rockler.com/rockler-insty-drive-tapered-drill-bits-and-countersinks-countersinks) (among others) makes drill bits that have countersinks built-in, like the image below.  I've used these quite a bit and I can tell you they work.  Just be careful that you don't put too much bending on the bit - they're pretty brittle when it comes to that (don't ask me how I know).

[image: insty-bit]

> Any advice on the type / size of screws to use for the hardboard would be great as well.

Hardboard that's only 3mm (1/8") is going to be hard to fasten with screws since it's so thin.  If you're set on using screws, I would use 6mm (1/4") hardboard or plywood instead with 25mm (1") screws.  These you would want to countersink since hardboard doesn't really allow screws to self-countersink.

Otherwise, if you're dead set on using 3mm hardboard as your subfloor, I would consider using construction adhesive and [ring shank (annular ring) nails](http://www.screwfix.com/p/easyfix-annular-ring-nails-2-x-25mm-0-5kg-pack/14437).  These are specifically designed to not work loose in situations like flooring so that they don't squeak.  The adhesive is just a bit of insurance in case the nails work loose.  The size I have linked is 2 x 25mm, which should be fine for the 3mm hardboard.  You may have to predrill the hardboard for the nails, just FYI.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the great answer grfrazee, exactly what I needed.

Comment: @AlexGoldie, while I appreciate you accepting my answer, It's usually a good idea to let the question stay unanswered for a bit to see if anyone comes along with a better one.  People with answers tend to steer away from answered questions.

Comment: +1 for glued 'n screwed (or ring-shank-nailed...)

Comment: Good answer -- except, are you sure about the "many slopes" thing? At least in EU screws are normed. Slope 90°, head diameter 2x screw diameter (except torx screws smaller than 5mm, they have larger heads presumably because they're not stable otherwise, but still 90° slope). Would be surprised if it was any different anywhere in the world.

Comment: @Damon, that may be the case.  All I can say is that in my experience, it always takes me a while to find the right countersink.

Comment: @Damon, yes there are multiple countersink head angles. There shouldn't be for screws intended for wood, but unfortunately construction details in screws vary. Another example of this is on the top of the head, q.v. comments posted elsewhere about the poor fit of many Pozi screws to the matching — of should that be 'matching'? :-) — driver tip.

Comment: Dunno, for me it should rather be matching than "matching" :-)  I only know what the angles are here because at one point, I neede to know exactly for one particular screw (drilling and sinking in V2A which was to be fixed in a wood plate, and needed an as even as possible surface). Looked at norm tables, and surprise, it was much more "clear" than expected, i.e. same angle and fixed ratio on diameter. I had kind of expected a "random" or at least not obvious head size for each diameter.